# svn add keyword property to all files

Tags: svn

I want add property keyword:Id to all *.java and *.js files in my project, using statnsart command

```
svn ps svn:keywords "Id" filename
```

How can I do it fast?
OS Windows
svn version 1.6.17 CollabNet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cmd script

```
for /f %%f in ('dir .\*java /s /B') do svn ps svn:keyword "Id" %%f
```